# Why Powershell ForEach loop gives incorrect output

Tags: azure, powershell, foreach, devops

I'm planning to generate a report on one of our app agent version, so I want to write a pipeline, that will go through every VM in every subscription and deploy a Custom Script Extension to every VM resource, retrieve CSE output value and put in into table, which later I want to send as a CSV file in email. Script code looks like this:

```
# ... variable initializations omitted

$subscriptions | ForEach-Object {
  Select-AzSubscription -Subscription $_.Name
  $vms = Get-AzVm -Status | Where-Object {$_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType -eq "Windows" -and $_.Name -notlike "azbecdns*" -and $_.Name -notlike "SF160SV0*" -and $_.PowerState -eq "VM running"}
  forEach ($vm in $vms) {

      $CSEvalidation = Get-AzVmExtension -VmName $vm.name -ResourceGroupName $vm.resourceGroupName | where-object {$_.Extensiontype -like "CustomScript*"} 
      if ($CSEvalidation -ne $null)
      {
        Remove-AzVmExtension -VmName $vm.name -ResourceGroupName $vm.resourceGroupName -Name $CSEvalidation.name -Force -ErrorAction Continue
      }
      Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension -TypeHandlerVersion 1.10 `
              -ResourceGroupName $vm.resourceGroupName `
              -VMName $vm.Name `
              -FileName $fileName `
              -ContainerName $containerName `
              -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName `
              -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey `
              -Run $fileName `
              -Location "West Europe" `
              -Name "CustomScriptExtension"

      #this var parse works and lists all vms
      $cseOutput = "test"

      #this doesn't work and only list last vm instance like in the very beginning
      $cseOutput = ((Get-AzVm -VmName $vm.name -ResourceGroupName $vm.resourceGroupName -Status).Extensions | Where {$_.Type -eq 'Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension'}).SubStatuses.Message[0]

      [PSCustomObject] @{
          VmName = $vm.name
          AgentVer = $cseOutput
        }
  }
} | Select-Object -Property VmName, AgentVer | Where-Object {$_.VmName -ne $null} | export-csv -NoTypeInformation -delimiter ';' -Path $(Pipeline.Workspace)\***.csv
```

CSV file only consists a last input, but when I check within the loop the content of a $hash variable, it shows a list of every VM and it's coressponding value. I've been trying to figure this out for days and still can't get a result I want. I also used an array object, but afair it's not really sufficient way of doing it because it's a very process time consuming method, yet still result was the same - csv file only consisted of last input. How should I modify script to get the result I want - being a CSV file with two columns - list of all vm names from all subscriptions and cse substatus message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

- *Hidden control characters* in the value of `$cseOutput` turned out to cause the problem, and eliminating them with `$cseOutput = $cseOutput -replace '\W'` solved it.

  - Note that this specific regex-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation removes all characters that aren't *word* characters from the string, i.e. anything isn't either an alphanumeric character or `_`.
  - To limit removal to *control characters* and *hidden format characters* only (see [Character classes in regular expressions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories)), use:
    `$cseOutput = $cseOutput -replace '[\p{Cc}\p{Cf}]'`

---

##### Original answer:

Your symptom is a bit of mystery: If the hashtable has multiple entries, you *should* see multiple rows, albeit with fixed column names `"Name","Key","Value"`; try with  `@{ one = 1; two = 2; three = 3 }.GetEnumerator() | ConvertTo-Csv` as a quick example.

---

> How should I modify script to get the result I want - being a CSV file with two columns - list of all vm names from all subscriptions and cse substatus message.

Note: **The question has since been updated to include the code below, with modifications.**

Emit `[pscustomobject]` instances with properties named for the desired CSV column names from your `foreach` loop and let PowerShell collect them in an array for you - or, preferable - switch to `ForEach-Object` and pipe those objects directly to `Export-Csv`:

```bash
# ... variable initializations omitted

$subscriptions |
  ForEach-Object {
    Select-AzSubscription -Subscription $_.Name
    $vms = Get-AzVm -Status | Where-Object { $_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType -eq 'Windows' -and $_.PowerState -eq 'VM running' }
    forEach ($vm in $vms) {
      $CSEvalidation = Get-AzVmExtension -VmName $vm.name -ResourceGroupName $vm.resourceGroupName -ErrorAction Continue | Where-Object { $_.Extensiontype -like 'CustomScript*' } 
      if ($CSEvalidation -ne $null) {
        $null = Remove-AzVmExtension -VmName $vm.name -ResourceGroupName $vm.resourceGroupName -Name $CSEvalidation.name -Force -ErrorAction Continue
      }

      $null = Set-AzVMCustomScriptExtension -TypeHandlerVersion 1.10 `
        -ResourceGroupName $vm.resourceGroupName `
        -VMName $vm.Name `
        -FileName $fileName `
        -ContainerName $containerName `
        -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName `
        -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey `
        -Run $fileName `
        -Location 'West Europe' `
        -Name 'CustomScriptExtension' `
        -ErrorAction Continue

      $cseOutput = ((Get-AzVm -VmName $vm.name -ResourceGroupName $vm.resourceGroupName -Status).Extensions | where { $_.Type -eq 'Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension' }).SubStatuses.Message[0]
      
      # Construct and output a [pscustomobject] instance with the desired
      # properties. The property names will become the CSV colum names.
      [pscustomobject] @{
        VmName = $vm.Name
        CseSubstatus = $cseOutput
      }

    }
  } | 
  Export-Csv -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation -Path $(Pipeline.Workspace)\***.csv
```